# Unable to sync with Oracle Standby database

Tags: oracle, standby, dataguard

I have created a standby database on Windows machine with version 10.2.0.1
For the first time for the database to sync I have copied the archive from the primary database. But on the switch from the primary database. The archive log doesn't ship to the standby database.

```
SQL> recover standby database;
ORA-00279: change 1248007 generated at 07/29/2012 22:46:37 needed for thread 1
ORA-00289: suggestion : E:\ARCHIVE\ARC00043_0778845461.001
ORA-00280: change 1248007 for thread 1 is in sequence #43


Specify log: {<RET>=suggested | filename | AUTO | CANCEL}

ORA-00308: cannot open archived log 'E:\ARCHIVE\ARC00043_0778845461.001'
ORA-27041: unable to open file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 2) The system cannot find the file specified.


ORA-01547: warning: RECOVER succeeded but OPEN RESETLOGS would get error below
ORA-01152: file 1 was not restored from a sufficiently old backup
ORA-01110: data file 1: 'E:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\ORADATA\STANDBY\SYSTEM01.DBF'
```

Earlier I took the cold backup to move the files.